# Meaning of “as”

Tags: meaning-in-context, as

Can someone explain the meaning and function of “as” here:

> Mediated by the hallucinatory hellscapes of Chicago drill **as** pioneered by Chief Keef, the UK version is essentially a South London chapter of trap.

Answer (score 4):

*Chicago drill* is a subgenre of rap. It, or some particular version of it, was pioneered (first introduced), by Chief Keef, a rapper.

[Wikipedia *Chief Keef*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Keef)

*as pioneered by Chief Keef* is a supplement that modifies *Chicago drill*, letting us know that CK introduced it.

One might say *Chicago drill was pioneered by CK*;  that could be a separate sentence. Here, that information is incorporated into another sentence as a supplement. That is the sense of *pioneered*; in the OP sentence it is included as a participle instead of as a separate verb.

The OP sentence could have omitted the word *as*, to say:
*Chicago drill, pioneered by CK, ...*
Including the word *as* could mean either that there are other versions of *Chicago drill* than CK's, or just that this subgenre may not be familiar to the reader and the writer is introducing it as such.

Comment: Would you mind describing the functions of "as" and "pioneered"? I think that that would help to explain the internal structure of that phrase.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I think I've clarified *pioneered*; the role of *as* there is a little less definite in my mind, as I've explained.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. It's a common enough expression (though the participles that can be used with it are fairly limited) but I'm struggling to characterise it, and I can't find it in the OED either.

Here are some other examples of the construction, from the iWeb corpus:

> ... will bring to life Helen Edmundsons show, as directed by Natalie Abrahami.

> due in great part to the popularity of the title song, as recorded by Rod McKuen.

> A turnover shirt collar with long points, as worn by the actor John Barrymore.

It's similar to a relative clause ("that is/was") but it can be restrictive or non-restrictive, and it has some semantic limitations that I can't quite grasp. It's often about something created or expressed.